# GAE Chat server for Android clients

Tags: android, google-app-engine, xmpp

I am looking for an optimal solution to implement chat server for android clients on GAE.

At the moment I use C2DM to notify particular users about new messages and pull data from server after such notification. But sometimes C2DM servers delay notification message and it stops to be realtime.

I also had a look on XMPP and it seems that it is mandatory to have an external XMPP server like google talk, so it is not what I am looking for too.

Is there another way to implement chat on GAE? Any advices are warmly appriceted!

Answer (score 2):

The Reason why you are experiencing Delay with C2DM is because it is not real time. Google actually says this: It isnt the most reliable way. It suggest having a third party server such as XMPP

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about C2DM, but in case if I use an external XMPP server I even have no need of GAE for chat feature... So as I understood there is no way to build a realtime chat on top of GAE and I should use an external server like XMPP or even Socket based approach to be deployed somewhere.

Comment: Yes. GAE is not real time so therefore it wouldnt be a good approach, taking that you would want your i.m to be real time and reliable. GAE would be to unreliable. Some user's may eventually not even be notified. Google doesnt put alot of efforts into this. They tell you this on the App Engine's googles code page/

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I already know and observed it on practice... but what can you reccomed? In fact I would like to keep my chat service somewhere in the cloud but as I know mostly all cloud platforms has restrictions like GAE...

Comment: "GAE is not real time" - this is untrue, and nor is it unreliable. The issue here is that the C2DM API is not real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement chat on App Engine using the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html), but the only supported clients for that are browsers. If you're prepared to make your Android app browser-based, that would be a solution - otherwise, you will have to look into third-party services, like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/).

Comment: Channel API supports a maximum channel creation rate of just 60 channels per minute even with billing enabled. That means even 100 simultaneous logins can not be supported!

Can we not post HTTP requests from one client to the App Engine server and then use cloud to device messaging for the client that should receive the message?